# PyBind11 generate Docstrings without Module name

Tags: python, pybind11

I am using PyBind11 to wrap C++ code for Python. Specifically, I have a package named "MyPackage" and a Module in there named "core". I now have exposed a class names "MyClass" with a function "MyFun". When I expose this and add a docstring "test" to it, the generated docstring is

`def MyFun(self: MyPackage.core.MyClass) -> None`

The "MyPackage.core." in the docstring makes this function signature long and difficult to read. Is there a way to generate the docstrings without this prefix? Or, at least, remove the ".core." because the user doesn't know what this even means.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not directly resolve the original question, since it will not modify the `__doc__` attribute on the resulting classes/functions.

However, if you are using sphinx autodoc to generate HTML documentation from a pybind module, you can workaround the incorrect modules using the [autodoc hooks](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#docstring-preprocessing).

For example, in my `conf.py` I have the following hook:

```py
def process_signature(app, what, name, obj, options, signature, return_annotation):
    """
    Emitted when autodoc has formatted a signature for an object. The event handler can return a new 
    tuple (signature, return_annotation) to change what Sphinx puts into the output.
    """
    signature = signature.replace('pybind_prefix.', 'actual_prefix.')
    return_annotation = return_annotation.replace('pybind_prefix.', 'actual_prefix.')
    return (signature, return_annotation)


def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-signature', process_signature)
```

This way the module names will at least be correct in your official library documentation.